# R package TensorFlow not accepting a dictionary when trying train a CNN

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm new to neural networks and am trying to build a CNN using the tensorflow R package. I've been trying to follow this example using a CNN to recognize handwritten numbers on kaggle:

https://www.kaggle.com/cd12631/using-r-and-tensorflow-to-build-cnn

In my case I'm building a CNN to detect whether a disease is present from an x-ray image. I've taken a small subset of x-ray images from:

https://www.kaggle.com/nih-chest-xrays/data

I've downsized the images to be 128x128 and read them in using the libraries png and pixmap. I put them into a dataframe where each row represents one image. There are 16,384 (128*128) columns for each gray-scale pixel along with an identifier of whether the disease is present as well as the name of each image.

I've closely followed the above example on how to make a CNN and am using the following steps to create my neural network:
Convolution layer 1 → Maxpooling layer1 → Convolution layer 2 → Maxpooling layer 2 → Flatten layer → Fully-connected layer 1 → Fully-connected layer 2

After creating all of these layers I'm trying to train the data. I'm starting small and only looping through it twice to make sure it's running correctly. When I try to run this for loop, I'm getting the following error:

CODE:

```
sess <- tf$Session()
init <- tf$global_variables_initializer()
sess$run(init)

for (i in 1:2){
  batch_seq <- round(100) %>% sample(seq_len(1000), size = .) 
  batches_xs <- train_data_1000[batch_seq,-(1:2)]
  batches_ys <- Train_Disease_Present[c(batch_seq)]
  sess$run(train_step_by_GD, feed_dict = dict(xs = batches_xs, ys = batches_ys, keep_prob_s= 0.55))
  if(i %% 50 == 0){
    print(paste("Step =", i, "|| Training Accuracy =", compute_accuracy(output_result, train_data_1000, Train_Disease_Present), sep = " "))
    print("---")
    print(paste("Step =", i, "|| Validation Accuracy =", compute_accuracy(output_result, test_data_500, Test_Disease_Present), sep = " "))
    print("=================================================")
  }
}
```

ERROR:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict'

Detailed traceback: 
  File "C:\Users\rorinan\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\ANACON~1\envs\R-TENS~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 895, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\rorinan\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\ANACON~1\envs\R-TENS~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1097, in _run
    np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)
  File "C:\Users\rorinan\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\ANACON~1\envs\R-TENS~1\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 531, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
```

I'm afraid I'm not familiar enough with Python to understand what the error is meaning. It looks like it has something to do with the needing a string or number instead of a dictionary. I've gone through and run the example code (the first link posted above) on Kaggle, and it runs perfectly -- using a dictionary. I've researched several other examples and they all seem to use a dictionary at this point. So I'm not sure why my code is giving me this error.

I'm running this on R version 3.4.4
Thanks in advance for any suggestions/help.

Thanks,
Tony

Comment: After talking with my buddy, I was passing a data frame to train my neural network. I changed it to a matrix and tried this code again and it worked. If anyone else is trying this in R, be sure to have the data in a matrix format. Is there a way to mark this as answered (if you can't tell, I'm new to asking questions in SO)?